# Which persistence method?

Tags: java, persistence

I'm building an application that downloads a set of images from a website, extracts some features from them and then allows a user to compare an image she submits to the downloaded set, to see which one is the closest. At the moment the application downloads the images and extracts the features from them. Then the image and the feature get wrapped in an object and stored in a map, with the key as the name of the image, and the value as the aforementioned wrapped object.
Because this is stored in memory, each time I start the application it has to go through the quite expensive process of downloading and feature extraction. It would be much quicker if it could just load this info from disk, but I'm not sure on the best way to go about it - I've thought about these options:

- RDMS: something like Postgres or SQLite
- NoSQL: something like
  Voldemort or Reddis
- Serialisation: use built in java methods to write
  objects to a file (could also be used in conjunction with a DB
  though...)

I want it to be really light weight; I want to keep the application as small as possible and keep configuration down to a minimum. For this reason serialisation seems like the way to go, but I'd like a second (or more) opinion on that, because something about doing it that way just feels wrong. I can't quite put my finger on why I feel like that...
I should also say that users can add images to the set when the application is running, I'd like to save these images too.

Comment: If you've got an object and want it later serialisation seems a natural option. Btw if you find java's inbuilt serialisation too slow look into kryo seriaisation which ive found considerably faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend serialzation - just too many pitfalls.

If what you have is really just a map, then i think any of the key-value stores ( like redis) would be appropriate.

If you have more complex data, then you might want to consider a database (whether SQL or no-sql).